# Open Cygwin.bat file in current working directory (Windows 10)

Tags: cygwin, regedit

New to Cygwin and trying to launch the batch file from the current working directory. I've done similar things before for .exe files in Windows 10 using the Registry Editor (see link):

https://www.windowscentral.com/how-launch-bash-shell-right-click-context-menu-windows-10

My Cygwin.bat file looks like this:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL
set HOME=C:\path\to\home
C:
chdir C:\cygwin64\bin
bash --login -i
ENDLOCAL
```

However, when I right click on a directory in order to "Open Cygwin.bat here", the terminal opens at `C:\path\to\home`. How can I make sure the terminal opens in the current working directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To obtain the expected result you need to use the `chere` package.

```
chere -i
```

is usually enough to create a proper `Bash Prompt Here` entry in Explorer left mouse button menu.

Please note that the usage of the `cygwin.bat` is not recommended anyway as does not use `mintty` as terminal